# ts-loader: import .ts module from other Yarn workspace

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarnpkg, ts-loader, yarn-workspaces

I have Yarn workspace structured like this:

```
/project
  package.json
  /packages
    /app
      package.json
      webpack.config.js
      tsconfig.json
      /src
        index.ts
    /api-adapter
      package.json
      /src
        api.ts
```

To build `/app` package I'm using Webpack with ts-loader. Here is configuration:

```
// /packages/app/webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/client/index.ts"),
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    output: {...}
};
```

and `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "webworker"]
  }
}
```

When I want to import module from other workspace:

```
// /packages/app/src/index.ts
import { fetchSomething } from "api-adapter/src/api";
```

an error occurred:

```
ERROR in ../api-adapter/src/api.ts
Module build failed (from /home/user/project/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Typescript emitted no output for /home/user/project/packages/api-adapter/src/api.ts.
```

but when I add extension to import, everything works fine:

```
// /packages/app/src/index.ts
import { fetchSomething } from "api-adapter/src/api.ts";
```

**How can I fix webpack config to import any workspace module as Typescript without extension?**

I've tried already:

```
rules: [{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: "ts-loader",
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  include: [
    __dirname,
    path.resolve(__dirname, "../packages")
  ],
}]
```

with:

```
ERROR in ../api-adapter/src/api.ts 3:34
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:34)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Comment: Adding `"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "../api-adapter/**/*.ts"]` to `packages/app/tsconfig.json` fixes the error for me, but I don't know if it is the right solution and I don't know ts-loader well enough to explain what is going on here.

Comment: You're right. ts-loader uses `tsconfig.json`, so I had to put `include` there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack config was correct. `ts-loader`found a file, but the compiler rejected it: `Error: Typescript emitted no output` because of path:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      ...
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "../../packages/**/*"
    ]
}
```